# Problem with I2C Sensor with Raspberry in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sensors, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to measure distance with the TOF10120 Laser sensor with the Raspberry Pi 4 in Matlab but after two times of read the value from the Sensor, the following value only give 0, please help
[the setup for raspberry connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXxRI.png)

[only 0 value were given after 2 times of read()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEed4.png)

Comment: From [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.